# Convert String to Object in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to save the string data into object. But I am getting error. Moreover, `json.loads(st)` not working for me.

```
import boto3
import os
import json

def handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucketname = os.getenv('bucketname')
    response = client.get_object (
            Bucket = bucketname,
            Key = 'constants.py')
    text = response['Body'].read()
    st = text.decode('utf-8').replace("'",'"')
    return st
```

This is the output I want it in an object so that I can treat it as contants file and use it in other files.

```
"NAME_SPACE = \"S2MohammadHassanNS\"\nURL_AVAILABILITY = \"Availability\"\nURL_LATENCY = \"Latency\"\nURLs = [\"google.com\",\"pahe.li\",\"bbc.com\"]\nAVAILABILITY_THRESHOLD = 1\nLATENCY_THRESHOLD = 0.22"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. A string in python *is* an object.

Comment: Maybe the OP means a dict, since in JSON the equivalent to a dict is an "object"

Comment: Yes I want to create a dict that contains the variables that can be utilized in file.

Comment: I want this `"URLs=[\"google.com\",\"pahe.in\",\"bbc.com\"]"` like `URLs=["google.com","pahe.in","bbc.com"]` and I can use this URLs too.

Comment: Have you tried `json.loads()`?

Comment: @Peter yes I tried it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly haha, will do an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is quite easy for you to just manually split the values. I'm using `ast.literal_eval` to convert to Python objects as it's safer than just the plain `eval`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

output = {}
for line in st.splitlines():
    var, value = line.split(' = ', 1)
    output[var] = literal_eval(value)
```

Gives the output:

```
{'NAME_SPACE': 'S2MohammadHassanNS', 'URL_AVAILABILITY': 'Availability', 'URL_LATENCY': 'Latency', 'URLs': ['google.com', 'pahe.li', 'bbc.com'], 'AVAILABILITY_THRESHOLD': 1, 'LATENCY_THRESHOLD': 0.22}
```